# Access Reports to Documents

Tags: 2010, reports, access, governance

Is it possible to find out who has accessed a document? Ideally I would like to run a report to show who have access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable auditing at the web application level and then enable Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties in the Site Collection Audit Settings in Site Settings of the site collection.  You can then collect data and run reports to see who accessed what and when.